# Unable to run react-native awesome app because gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I try to run the sample app by doing a react-native run-android. I get the following error. 
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5/gradle-3.5.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5/gradle-3.5.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I saw some sites saying to get the cert from the site, but it is just a download link I cannot figure out how to actually get the cert. Since I can download the pom file can I just put it somewhere in the react-native file structure?

Comment: Do you use a proxy?

Comment: No. No proxy set up.